# Accessing css selector contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am trying to style a contact form 7 within a Revolution Slider I can't to get the right selector for the label. I have shown what I have tried below. I am using the last version of wordpress and of revolution slider.

This is the css that I have tried.

```
/* ******************* */
/* FITTING ADJUSTMENTS */
/* ******************* */

/* default height for <textarea> message field */
.rev_slider .wpcf7-textarea {height: 200px}



    .wpcf7
    {

     color:black; 
    }

    .label {
     color:black;   
    }
```

And this is my contact form 7 module how would I access the label.

```
    <label> Your Name (required)
        [text* your-name] </label>

    <label> Your Email (required)
        [email* your-email] </label>

    <label> Subject
        [text your-subject] </label>

    <label> Your Message
        [textarea your-message] </label>

    [submit "Send"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some samples for CF7 elements:

```
.wpcf7 label { /* for labels */ }
.wpcf7 textarea { /* for labels */ }
.wpcf7 input { /* for labels */ }
```

and so on.
Note that, you should not use "." before the string if it is HTML tag (such as div, label, input etc.) So ".label" and ".textarea" are wrong usage.

"." is used only for CSS class name selectors.

.wpcf7-textarea - this is also wrong usage. Just use .wpcf7 textarea instead.